# moongose sort user by proximity and after by rating

Tags: mongodb, filter, location

**Can I sort by proximity first and second by rating in he same database query? How can I do this by Moongose?**

Currently I have a user list sorted first by proximity and second by rating, it is correct, and it works fine, but I sort it after the query using the **[sort()](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_array_sort.asp)** javascript function, here is my code:

```
FILTER = { 
        $and: [
        {"user" :{"$in" : user_ids}},
        {"active": true},
        { "geopoint": { $exists: true } },
        { "geopoint": 
            {
                $nearSphere: {
                    $geometry: {
                        type: 'Point',
                        coordinates: [lng , lat],
                    },
                    $minDistance: 0,
                    $maxDistance: maxDistance
                },
            }
        }],   
      }

      const PROFILES = await Profile.find( FILTER, async ( err, profiles ) => {      
                     
        })
        .populate('user', '_id verified')
        .select(exclude)
        .limit(max_results) // Get all or only 10 from db
        .skip( skip ) // Skip the first 5 or skip cero is value is cero
        // .sort( { global_rate: -1 } )
        .exec();
    
        if( PROFILES.length === 0 ) {
            return [];
        }

 PROFILES.map( (profile: any) => { 



        if( lat && lng && profile.geopoint && profile.geopoint.coordinates && profile.geopoint.coordinates.length > 0 ) {

            const distance_to_buyer_location: number =  GeocodeService.getDistance(lat, lng, profile.geopoint.coordinates[1], profile.geopoint.coordinates[0]);
            profile.geopoint.distance = distance_to_buyer_location;
        }
        return profile;
    });  

    return PROFILES;
```

Finally I sort the data at the runtime (I really don't like this solution):

```
            // Reorder by rating
            const sort_by_rate = userList.sort( (a, b) => {
                
                if (a.global_rate < b.global_rate) return 1;
                if (b.global_rate < a.global_rate) return -1;
            
                return 0;
            
            });

             // Reorder by distance
             const sort_by_distance = sort_by_rate.sort( (a, b) => {
                
                // console.log('a.geopoint.distance < b.geopoint.distance ', `${a.geopoint.distance} > ${b.geopoint.distance }`);

                return  Number(a.geopoint.distance) - Number(b.geopoint.distance);
                        
            });
```

Many thanks